# DIR command that ignores files with multiple extensions

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, dir

I have a directory containing a single `.exe` that I need to find using DIR. However, I also have files in the same directory that end in `.vshost.exe`.
I always end up with both files matched to my `*.exe` pattern.

i.e the directory contains `test.exe` and `test.vshost.exe` (both files have the same name minus the extension.)

How can I match just the `.exe`, and not `.vshost.exe`? I feel like this should be relatively easy using * and ? but I can't seem to find much about excluding a file like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible with *only* the `DIR` command, however it can be combined with the `FINDSTR` command.

I'm focusing on the more general question, rather than the specific question regarding `.exe` files, but you can easily modify this to narrow it down.

The `FINDSTR` command supports regular expression searches on the output which allows us to filter out files with more than one period in the filename.

```
DIR /B | FINDSTR /V /R "[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$"
```

I would suggest wrapping into a `FOR` loop as follows to do something with the returned file list:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('DIR /B ^| FINDSTR /V /R "[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$"') DO ECHO %%a
```

### Breakdown

In this explanation, `<...>` is a placeholder for things that will be explained later. It's only there to simplify.

- **`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('<...>') DO ECHO %%a`**
  Using `"tokens=*"` or `"delims="` in your `FOR` loop allows processing filenames with spaces. Replace `ECHO %%a` with whatever command(s) you want to run.
- **`DIR /B`**
  Using the `/B` switch on the `DIR` command uses bare format, including only the filenames. This is required for the `FINDSTR` command to function as we want.
- **`^|`**
  It is important to escape the `|` character when used inside the command portion of a `FOR` loop. Otherwise you'll get a syntax error because it thinks you're trying to pipe the incomplete `FOR` loop into something else.
- **`FINDSTR /V /R "<...>"`**
  The `/V` switch tells `FINDSTR` to remove matches from the list and the `/R` switch turns on Regular Expression mode.
- **`[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$`**

  - `[^\.]*` will match any string of characters that do not include the `.` character.
  - `\.` will match the `.` character.
  - `$` is the "end of line" character, meaning that this regular expression *must* be at the end of the filename. This allows us to match files with any number of periods in the filename such as `test.vhost.exe.bak`.

### Further Reading

- [Dir - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [Findstr - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For (command) - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
dir *.exe /b | findstr /i ".*[^\.]*.*\.exe$"
```

in words: find a string in .exe files that does not contain a dot other than the one in .exe

Comment: Consider adding a note explaining why this might work if you want to make it even more helpful.

Comment: The two `.*` in the pattern will allow any number of literal dots, and the class `[^*\.]` without a quantifier is pretty useless.